# Static block at the end of the page Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Move the static block at the end of the page. I searched a lot for solution. But, no luck.

I tried swapping of echo in catalog/category/view.phtml. But it did not work.

```
   <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?> <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

I do not want to use css to move the block at the end of the page, It creates other alignment issues. 
How to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

**before** and **after** attributes but only work in one of two cases

When you insert into a `core/text_list block`

When your template block calls `getChildHtml` without any paramaters

When you do like this

```
<reference name="root">
   <block type="core/template" name="your_block" before="content" template="page/html/your-block.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

you're telling Magento

Hey Magento, put the example_block inside the root block.

those blocks are being explicitly rendered.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('example_block') ?>
```

However, there's two cases where order matters. First, if you call

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Answer (score 0):

swapping of echo work in magento. I will be :-

```
<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
```

Please check the theme, where you are editing 
file. File Path should be:- `app/design/frontend/default/your theme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`